# Equivalent resistance of an unequal geometrically progressing arrangement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am a high school student and while going through one of my papers, I encountered this problem which I couldn't seem to solve.

$\textbf{Question:}$
Find the equivalent resistance between the two nodes in the arrangement given below,
[image: The arrangement given, note that, the boxes are resistances!]

Now, I know how to solve question involving an infinite ladder of equal resistances and the Questions involving equal geometrically progressing arrangement such as below:
[image]
But, I couldn't figure out any recursive relation in the question which would have made me able to solve it. Need help!

Comment: I need an answer, I never knew that questions go unanswered on stackexchange.